# How to add a post slug to a url?

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, urls, advanced-custom-fields, slug

For a project i'm working on I try to add the slug of a custom post type to the end of an url.
The case:

When a user fills out a contact form, the email that gets send needs to have a link to the users profile post. The name of the post type is `actor`. The slug (or whatever needs to be added to the url) needs to be dynamic. So for example when John Do is logged in and fills out the form, the link should look like this: `example.com/actor/john-do.`

This are the codes I tried out.

```
    function acf_load_field( $field ) {
    
//  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
//  $profile_link = "example.com/en/actor/$current_user->ID";
    
//  $slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() );
//  $profile_link = "example.com/en/actor/$slug";
    
    $post_type = get_post_type();
    $post_type_data = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
    $post_type_slug = $post_type_data->rewrite['slug'];
    $profile_link = "example.com/en/actor/$post_type_slug";
    
    $field['default_value'] = $profile_link;
    return $field;
}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=profile_link_actor_profile', 'acf_load_field');
```

The last code outputs the url with the custom post type of the page it is shown on. Which is called `project`.

I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to add the slug the `actor` post type to the url.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how are you registering the actor post-type? you would use [the post-type's rewrite argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#rewrite) to set a base url slug for that post-type.

Comment: I created the post-type with a plugin called CPT-UI. Or is that not what you meant? Thank you for sharing the link. I will see if I can gind something on there.

Comment: In CPT-UI we can use the "Custom Rewrite Slug" option to set the slug for the post-type. Is that what you were looking for? [further reading](https://www.scratchcode.io/how-to-change-custom-post-type-slug-in-wordpress/#cpt-ui-plugin)

Comment: Apologize for the late response.
Thanks, that did the trick :)